# Recompile due to "preprocessor define" on a .h

Tags: c, linux, makefile, dependencies

## My problem

I'm compiling multiple targets with a single makefile, which so far works quite good. My problem is that one of those target shares a .h file (`hash.h`), which changes according to a macro: `HASHTABLE_USING_LISTS`

So, when the Makefile is ran, everythin is compiled, but `practica2_list_bench`, which should be using the version with the `HASHTABLE_USING_LISTS` defined, ends up linking to an old `.o` object which was compiled without it.

It ends up with memory corruptions all over the program and a beautiful `SIGSEV`.

It is clear that I must somehow tell the Makefile to recompile whenever a .h file changes (in this case, it changes by specifying that macro).

Here is all my Makefile:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
# This is the makefile that generates the executable

# If compiing with -ansi, we should use
#   -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-implicit-function-declaration

CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -g
LFLAGS = -lm

INCLUDE_BENCH = -I$(CURDIR) -Ibenchmark

FILES_O         =
FILES_C         =

TARGET          = practica2
CURRENT         = 

NAME            = $(TARGET)
NAME_BENCH      = $(TARGET)_bench
NAME_LIST       = $(TARGET)_list_bench

.PHONY: bare bench list
all: bare bench list

bare: FILES_C   = main.c parsing.c linked-list.c hash.c
bare: FILES_O   = $(subst .c,.o,$(FILES_C))

bench: FILES_C  = benchmark/main_bench.c parsing.c benchmark/benchmark.c linked-list.c hash.c
bench: CFLAGS   += $(INCLUDE_BENCH)
bench: CURRENT  = _BENCH
bench: FILES_O  = $(subst .c,.o,$(FILES_C))

list: FILES_C   = benchmark/main_bench.c parsing.c benchmark/benchmark.c linked-list.c benchmark/hash_list.c
list: CFLAGS    += -DHASHTABLE_USING_LISTS $(INCLUDE_BENCH)
list: CURRENT   = _LIST
list: FILES_O   = $(subst .c,.o,$(FILES_C))

clean:
    -/bin/rm -f *.o benchmark/*.o $(NAME) $(NAME_BENCH) $(NAME_LIST)

%.o: %.c hash.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

bare bench list: $$(FILES_O)
    gcc $(FILES_O) -o $(NAME$(CURRENT)) $(LFLAGS)
```

I am completely out of ideas. I had a lot of trouble to come up with this "multi-target" "second expansion" version, and I don't know how I should continue from here on.

Note that several improvements might be done, but that's another issue I'll address once this is solved.

Thank you!

Comment: The header file does not change, you're defining a macro which tells the compiler to preprocess the header differently. You have a couple of options: Make could use an extra file to keep track of which executable you last built, you could keep two versions of each object file under two different names, you could maintain two object directories to hold the object files for the two executables, or you could rebuild all of the executables every time (crude but effective). What sounds good?

Comment: @Beta I guess having separate folders would be the way to go. How would I prepend to each entry on FILES_O some text? As in `FILES_O = $(prepend objs/,$(subs .c,.o,$(FILES_C)))`? GCC will be smart enough to "detect" those .o files are in different folders and generate them accordingly?

Comment: @Beta `addprefix` seems to be my command. I'll test it.

Comment: @Beta Done and working, thanks. I'll answer myself with the final version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to depend your `.o` file(s) on `Makefile`. That way, if you edit the Makefile to include `-D...` or not, the `.o` files will be recompiled.

Comment: That's not what I ended up doing, but w/e. Nor is this the answer to my question. I'll accept it as no better answer has been given. I solved it another way!

Comment: Yes... I spent quite a bit of time reading your question, really took me some time.  And would you believe it, I still did not apparently manage to understand it and provided an answer to a different question.  How dumb I am!  You should post several more of questions like this, so I can practice my comprehension skills.

Comment: Don't misunderstand me, I didn't mean you didn't put effort into it nor that you were wrong. I accepted your answer because it is indeed correct and provides some insight into it. However, it does not help on why I can't make Make recompile whenever I change a flag, as in a define. Then again, your answer is not dumb and I'm sorry if it did seem I said that, I was in a hurry and I hadn't time enough to explain myself. I hope you can understand and forgive me.